# Want to print set of values in an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am new to Ruby programming and currently working on an automation, I have the following array.

```
arr = [
  ["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_personal_care_appliances"],
  ["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_drugstore"],
  ["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_pantry"],
  ["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_pet_products"],
  ["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_grocery"]
]
```

I would like to print the last element of each element (array) of `arr`, here `"values gl_personal_care_appliances"`, `"gl_drugstore"`, `"gl_pantry"`, `"gl_pet_products"` and `"gl_grocery'`.

I tried few methods taking reference from net but no success. Any lead or assistance

Comment: Used arry.map {|row| row[2]} and got the outcome.

Comment: Can you edit the array to be effectively an array? It is not clear if it is multidimensional.

Comment: Can you show what _few_ methods you tried?

Comment: cval = Array.new
ck = Array.new
cval = <array with data as above>

cval.each do |key|
ck <<  key.values

ctgry =  ck.map {|row| row[4]}
final_ctgry = ctgry.reject { |c| c.empty? }  // this removes empty rows in an array

Answer (score 6):

If the array is like this:

```
array =[ 
["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_personal_care_appliances"],
["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_drugstore"],
["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_pantry"],
["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_pet_products"],
["DealsNEvents-9", "GLOBAL", "dom_validation_config", "4", "gl_grocery"]
]
```

Then, one option is build a new array containing the required elements:

```
array.map { |e| e.last }
# => ["gl_personal_care_appliances", "gl_drugstore", "gl_pantry", "gl_pet_products", "gl_grocery"]
```

Or the compact version:

```
array.map(&:last)
```

But if you just want to print the strings:

```
array.each { |e| puts e.last }

# => gl_personal_care_appliances
# => gl_drugstore
# => gl_pantry
# => gl_pet_products
# => gl_grocery
```